# Importing functions from a lib. / dll file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a library file.

Is it possible to extract its functions in a solution done with Visual Studio?

Is it the same procedure as exporting functions into a dll file?

Comment: by extract, do you mean statically link the library into your executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`dumpbin`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) utility is probably what you are looking for. It is able to give you information about symbols inside the library files. You can use it from the VS Command Prompt and for further reference, look at Microsoft's referenece: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429